# enter into 2d array with user preference

Tags: java

I need to get following as keyboard inputs to a 2d array.

```
1 34 56
1 6 89
2 34 67 23 45
3 56 67 78 89 45 23
1 45 78
```

The input is built as follows: the first entry of each row specifies the number of pairs and is followed by the respective number of pairs. How can this be achieved

```
int[][] arr2 = new int[n][];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    arr2[i] = new int[10];
    arr2[i][0] = x.nextInt();

    arr2[i] = new int[arr2[i][0]];

    for (int h = 1; h < 2 * arr2[i][0]; h++) {  
        x.nextInt();
    }
}
```

Comment: You are storing the number of pairs in an array element, and then replacing that array with a new array, which, by specification, is filled with zeros; when you use the zeroth element in the for loop guard, it will be zero. Try storing the number of pairs in a local variable, and make the length of the new inner array twice that length.

Answer (score 0):

I think you do not have to override the array with the length of the row and then replace it again, and then only assign the array to the respective element

```
int[][] userInput = new int[rowCount][];
for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
    int pairCount = x.nextInt(); 
    userInput[i] = new int[pairCount * 2];
    for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < 2 * pairCount; rowIndex++) {
        userInput[i][rowIndex] = x.nextInt();    
    }  
}
```